# Restore lightdm start at boot time

Tags: virtualbox, boot, ubuntu-16.04, xorg

I have Ubuntu 16.04 running on virtualbox. I did install guest additions from the host. While I was troubleshooting a black screen of death, I had set it to boot to console.

Now. I don't remember how can I restore the boot to start `lightdm` automagically. I currently have to run

```
$ sudo service lightdm start
$ sudo killall Xorg
```

on a console before I can actually use it. `lightdm` gives me a black screen on `tty7` until I kill `Xorg`. I have no idea why that happens.